# How to remove a pair of repeated occurrences in a list in c++? (keep elements that appear only once)

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, stl

I've tried using `unique` but `unique` removes the duplicate only.

What my program is suppose to do is for example the list contains `1,2,2,2,3,4,4`. I am suppose to only remove the the pair of the number that is repeated and the output should be `1,2,3` (a pair of 2 and 4 is removed).

Comment: What if the list contains `1,2,3,2,4,2,4`? The output should be `1,2,3,2,4,2,4` or `1,2,3`?

Comment: it should be 1,2,3.The list is sorted first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate through data and remove pairs (*[Live code](http://ideone.com/LhxWsA)*):

```
list<int> data{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6};

for (auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end();)
{
    auto n = std::next(i);

    if (n == data.end())
        break;

    if (*i == *n)
    {
        i = data.erase(i);
        i = data.erase(i);
    }
    else
        i++;
}
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Also `1 2 3`  for `1 2 2 2 3 4 4`.

Above code works since C++11, if you don't have it, try this:

```
for (list<int>::iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end();)
{
    list<int>::iterator n = i; 
    n++;

    if (n == data.end())
        break;

    if (*i == *n)
    {
        i = data.erase(i);
        i = data.erase(i);
    }
    else
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I get this error saying ‘next’ is not a member of ‘std’. Any clue on this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `sort` and `unique` functions to do this.

```
std::sort (my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end() );
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
it = std::unique (my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end() );
my_vector.resize( std::distance(my_vector.begin(),it) );
```

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/   -- this has an example where you can use `predicate comparison` to customize the behavior of `unique`.

EDIT -- You may also want to look at `std::adjacent_find` if you are interested in removing consecutive elements.

EDIT -- If all you care is to delete consecutive elements, first sort the list, and then iterate over it. If two elements are consecutive, delete both of them using `std::remove_if` or something like that.

Comment: `std::unique` can be modified using `predicate` function to achieve your custom needs :) I just gave an example.

Comment: i've tried adjacent_find and if the list contains the same number one after another for eg 1,2,2,2,3..it removes all the 2's.My requirement is to only remove a pair of the 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily loop through the list. Get the first item and search for other items for an exact match, if any found remove both. When the loop ends you should have a list without any pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can come up with a sentinel value that's not in your list, here's a slightly more generic way to handle this problem.  As a side benefit, this probably works much better on vectors, since vector::erase is pretty slow.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <class ITR>
void replace_pairs_with_sentinel(ITR begin, ITR end,
    const typename std::iterator_traits<ITR>::value_type& sentinel)
{
    // handle empty sequence
    if ( begin == end ) return;

    // ensure no sentinel values exist
    assert ( std::find(begin, end, sentinel) == end );

    ITR prev = begin++;
    while ( begin != end ) {
        if ( *begin == *prev ) {
            *prev = *begin = sentinel;
        }
        prev = begin++;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int data[] = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6};
    std::vector<int> v( data, data + sizeof(data) / sizeof(int) );

    replace_pairs_with_sentinel( v.begin(), v.end(), -INT_MAX );
    std::vector<int>::iterator end_itr = std::remove( v.begin(), v.end(), -INT_MAX );
    v.resize( end_itr - v.begin() );
    std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will work fine for std::list.  This approach  requires the container to be sorted, but you said that assumption is valid.